# TYPO3 Extension Builder v10: records from BE not showing up in List View

Tags: typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I created a new extension "lecturers" with the TYPO3 Extension Builder (v.10.0.1).
As default actions, I added list, show and create. After creating the extension, I did not modify any of the files except the list template.

Usually, I add new data within the BE, as it can be seen in the image: [image: two records of data in the BE]

But when I open the list view, no data is shown. Also, the repository is empty (<f:debug>{lecturers}</f:debug>.
However, when I added a record within the create view, the repository as well as the list view includes that one record.

Does anyone know which lines of code I am missing, to include the BE records in my repository as well? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After removing the setting of persistence in the generated folder TypoScript/setup.typoscript it worked